# Run a .sh on startup

Tags: bash, startup, .sh

I am creating a restore backup. When it start up I want it to run a .sh file that run a application and then reboots with out asking for a passcode. I have already built the .sh file but I have try adding the script to that on startup application. But it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the /etc/rc.local with a text editor.
Add the following line at the bottom before the exit 0 line.

/bin/sh /path/to/file.sh

Save, exit, reboot. Try it out.

Comment: Do NOT have `/path/to/file.sh` on an unavailable filesystem (user's encrypted `$HOME` when user is not logged in)